# Uwp multiple views theme

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Thanks in advance.

I have a problem and I search on google a long time. I can't find a way to fix it.

In uwp, I want to let user to custom own theme.

and of course, I have three themes, Light, Dark and follow system.

To simplely, In App class Constructor, I have code:

```
Current.RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme.Dark;
```

I changed the theme to dark. as this pic:

[image: Dark theme]

When this lose his focus

it will be :

[image]

it is normal. but I open a new window in app:

when the secondary window have focus:

[image]

it is normal too. but when the secndary window lose focus:

[image]

text color is dark theme's white, is normal, but background is white too, it is light theme's background!

I tried to set the secondary window's frame's RequestedTheme to Dark:

```
var newWindow = Window.Current;
                var newAppView = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();

                newAppView.Title = "New window";

                var frame = new Frame();
                frame.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
                frame.Navigate(typeof(NavPage),"youareNotMain");
                newWindow.Content = frame;
                newWindow.Activate();

                await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(
                    newAppView.Id,
                    ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum,
                    currentAV.Id,
                    ViewSizePreference.UseMinimum);
            });
```

but not work.

I tried to set theme in secondary window class；

```
this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;
```

it is not work too.

it is all have dark theme when have focus,  but lose focus have a mistake.

thanks for your help.

[example in Google Drive(ZIP)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XysGeceg20a2O8Q-bj0V1V9TJFJnismT)
I only use

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">

                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="Back" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="White" TintOpacity=".6"/>

                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="Backdrop" TintColor="White" TintOpacity=".6"/>
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="White" TintOpacity=".8"/>

            </ResourceDictionary>

            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">

                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="Back" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="Black" TintOpacity=".6"/>

                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="Backdrop" TintColor="Black" TintOpacity=".6"/>
                <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="Black" TintOpacity=".6"/>

            </ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Using the official sample cannot reproduce this problem and it seems you've added fluent design feature in your XAML.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Yeah, I had create a example and I upload to google drive,  then I update my question. I put link in my question. please help , thanks